# Recommended Approach To Customization Of Alfresco Community Edition Docker Compose Installation

Tags: alfresco

I have been given the assignment of customizing an Alfresco Community Edition 7.0 installation from docker-compose. I have looked at the resources and am looking for the best approach. I also see a github repository for acs-packaging but that appears to be related to the enterprise version. I could create images off the existing images and build my own docker-compose file that loads my images. This seams to be a bit of an overkill for changes to the alfresco global properties file.

For example, I am moving the DB and file share to docker volumes and mapping to host directories. I can add the volume for Postgres easily to the docker compose file. The file share information appears to be less straight forward. I see there is a global property that specifies the directory in alfresco-global.properties (dir.root=/alfresco/data). It is a little less clear how many of the docker components need the volumes mapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should externalize your directory to setup persistence data storage for content store, solr etc. in your custom docker image.

```
volumes:
            - alfdata:/usr/local/tomcat/alf_data
volumes:
            - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
            - solrdata:/opt/alfresco-search-services/data
volumes:
            - amqdata:/opt/activemq/data
```

Please refer the [link](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-docker-installer#docker-volumes) for more information.

**-Arjun M**

Comment: Thanks, that handles the parts that needs to be exposed as volumes.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, so that it will be useful for others

Answer (score 1):

Consider going through this discussion, and potentially using the community template:

- https://github.com/Alfresco/acs-community-packaging/pull/201
- https://github.com/keensoft/docker-alfresco

Comment: Do you know if this has been update for Community Edition 7.0?

Comment: I made the changes and Community 7.0 and it is working file on Windows. I am now trying to run on Linux and seeing permissions issues writing to directories mapped under volumes. What does docker-compose handle the user the containers are running under?